# Inserting a portion of a PDF as an image

Tags: pdf

I want to insert some images from some sources in my latex document. I have taken the screenshots and saved each image as a PDF in my system.

However, this PDF has image saved in A4 size while my images are around a quarter of A4 page. I only want to insert the part of the image in latex and not the whole A4 page of PDF.

How can I do this?

Comment: [Briss](http://briss.sourceforge.net) is a very nice tool that might help you achieve what you need. You can crop your pdf file just as you need it,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this with the `pdfcrop` utility which should be part of most TeX distributions. On the command line in the folder where your pdf (e.g. my.pdf) is run the following command to crop the image in place

```
pdfcrop my.pdf my.pdf
```

Then include the image in LaTeX using pdfpages e.g. with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf{my.pdf}
\end{document}
```

or just as an image with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{my.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You will probably get a lot more and quicker responses on http://tex.stackexchange.com